# How to run all android instrumentation tests on multiple devices parallelly

Tags: android, gradle, adb, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to run all my espresso tests on multiple devices simultaneously using `adb shell am instrument` command. Wondering if there is a way. I'm not trying to distribute my tests across devices, i want to run all of them on all connected devices.

I tried to use gradle command but i'm not able to change the runner (Allure).

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the processes in the background

```
serialnos=( "serialno1" "serialno2" "serialno3" )
for s in ${serialnos[@]}; do
  adb -s "$s" shell am instrument ... &
done
```